# Android PayPal OnClickListener is not working

Tags: android, paypal, oncreate, onclicklistener

I am trying to connect the PayPal to my app. Basically my app will have one Scan button and one PayPal Button on the screen. Scan button calls the ZXing library and scan the barcodes. However, I still cannot connect with PayPal button yet because `OnClickListener` and `getApplicationContext()` is not working. I have read PayPal documentation , StackOverflow and still couldn't work out. I am wondering what is wrong with my code? Any Suggestions please?Thank you for your help :)

```
package thet.mon.aye;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;

import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
import com.paypal.android.MEP.CheckoutButton;
import com.paypal.android.MEP.PayPal; 
import com.paypal.android.MEP.PayPalReceiverDetails;
import com.paypal.android.MEP.PayPalPayment;
import android.content.Context;

public class DevilscanActivity extends ListActivity implements onClickListener {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

private static final int ACTIVITY_CREATE=0;
private BarcodeDBAdapter mDbHelper;
private Cursor mNotesCursor;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    mDbHelper = new BarcodeDBAdapter(this);
    mDbHelper.open();
    fillData();
    PayPal ppObj = PayPal.getInstance();

       final Button scanButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    scanButton.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {  

            Intent intent1 = new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN");
            intent1.putExtra("SCAN_MODE", "1D_CODE_MODE");
            startActivityForResult(intent1, 0);

        }

    });

CheckoutButton launchPayPalButton = ppObj.getCheckoutButton(this, PayPal.BUTTON_278x43, CheckoutButton.TEXT_PAY);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
    params.bottomMargin = 10;
launchPayPalButton.setLayoutParams(params);
    launchPayPalButton.setOnClickListener((OnClickListener) this);
((RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.RelativeLayout01)).addView(launchPayPalButton);


}
static public PayPal initWithAppID(Context context, String appID, int server)
{    
        PayPal ppObj;
    if (ppObj == null) {
        try {

            ppObj = PayPal.initWithAppID(getApplicationContext(),"", PayPal.ENV_NONE);
            } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        ppObj.setShippingEnabled(false);
    }

     }



private void fillData() {
    // Get all of the rows from the database and create the item list
    mNotesCursor = mDbHelper.fetchAllNotes();
    startManagingCursor(mNotesCursor);

    // Create an array to specify the fields we want to display in the list (only TITLE)
    String[] from = new String[]{BarcodeDBAdapter.KEY_BARCODE_TYPE};

    // and an array of the fields we want to bind those fields to (in this case just text1)
    int[] to = new int[]{R.id.text1};

    // Now create a simple cursor adapter and set it to display
    SimpleCursorAdapter notes = 
        new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.barcode_row, mNotesCursor, from, to);
    setListAdapter(notes);
}


public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent1) {
    //intent1 = new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN");
   // intent1.putExtra("SCAN_MODE", "QR_CODE_MODE");
   // startActivityForResult(intent1, 0);
    if (requestCode == 0) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            String contents = intent1.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT");
            String format = intent1.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT_FORMAT");
            mDbHelper.createNote(contents, format);

        } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
            // Handle cancel
        }
    }

}
```

}